# useEffect hook to update state from a function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, oop, google-cloud-firestore, functional-programming

I have a function that returns an object.

It looks like this

```
const aggResults = data => {
  const { surveyName, questionId } = data
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  const surveyData = db.collection('surveys').doc(surveyName)

  return surveyData.onSnapshot(doc => {
    console.log('test', doc.data().aggResults[questionId])
    return doc.data().aggResults[questionId]
  })
}
```

Frome the same file, I call my function like this

```
 {
      ...
      output: {
        ...
        function: () => aggResults({ surveyName: '...', questionId: '...' }),
      },
    },
```

In a separate file, I want to update my state based with what `aggResults` returns.

I have used a useEffect hook to do this

```
const [data, updateData] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_.isUndefined(question.output)) {
      question.output.function().then(res => updateData(res))
    } else {
      console.log('q', question.output)
    }
  }, [question])
```

The error I'm getting at the moment is **TypeError: question.output.function().then is not a function**

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot) doesn't return a promise.  It returns an unsubscribe function that you call to remove the listener from the DocumentReference.  You can see an example of this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).  When you call `question.output.function()`, it is going to return you this unsubscribe function.

Snapshot listeners are for receive updates to a document as it changes over time.  If you're trying to do a single query without listening for ongoing changes, you should use `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()`, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).  `get()` returns a promise that resolves with a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) contains the document data.

Comment: Hmm...I need `onSnapshot` for real time updates, I have tried `get()` but it returns old data.

Comment: get() only returns old data while offline.  While online, it accesses the server.  If you need realtime updates, then you're going to have to write code inside the onsnapshot callback to deliver the results to your UI.  It won't return the data directly from aggResults as I expained.